# Errors with CIFilter and Swift 2: '_' is not convertible to 'String' + Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-image, nsimage, swift2

I used this piece of code in Swift 1.2 (adapted from an Objective-C snippet found on SO) to apply a blur effect on an image.

It was working ok but I can't convert it to Swift 2, I'm not sure I understand the error messages and I can't find documentation about what has changed.

Error message:

> '_' is not convertible to 'String'

And:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Extension that worked with 1.2:

```
extension NSImage {
    func gaussianBlurOfRadius(radius: CGFloat) -> NSImage {
        let image = self
        image.lockFocus()
        let beginImage = CIImage(data: image.TIFFRepresentation!)
        // error message highlights the next line
        let params = [kCIInputImageKey: beginImage, kCIInputRadiusKey: radius]
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: params)
        var output = filter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage
        let rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)
        output.drawInRect(rect, fromRect: rect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.CompositeSourceOver, fraction: 1)
        image.unlockFocus()
        return image
    }
}
```

[image]

*UPDATE:*

Following Duncan's idea, I've added an explicit type to the declaration:

```
let params: [String: AnyObject] = [kCIInputImageKey: beginImage, kCIInputRadiusKey: radius]
```

[image]

but that doesn't fix it, though it removes the error message about type ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension NSImage {
    func gaussianBlurOfRadius(radius: CGFloat) -> NSImage {
        let image = self
        image.lockFocus()
        let beginImage = CIImage(data: image.TIFFRepresentation!)!
        let params = [kCIInputImageKey : beginImage, kCIInputRadiusKey: radius]
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: params)!
        let output = filter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage
        let rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        output.drawInRect(rect, fromRect: rect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.CompositeSourceOver, fraction: 1)
        image.unlockFocus()
        return image
    }
}
```

or

```
extension NSImage {
    func gaussianBlurOfRadius(radius: CGFloat) -> NSImage {
        let image = self
        image.lockFocus()
        let beginImage = CIImage(data: image.TIFFRepresentation!)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
        filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        let output = filter.valueForKey("outputImage") as! CIImage
        let rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        output.drawInRect(rect, fromRect: rect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.CompositeSourceOver, fraction: 1)
        image.unlockFocus()
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: @EricD. The issue was the value returned from CIImage not being unwrapped

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, Swift is trying to create a Dictionary object with fixed types.

try

```
let params: [String: AnyObject] = 
  [kCIInputImageKey: beginImage, kCIInputRadiusKey: radius]
```

Or perhaps

```
let params: NSDictionary = 
  [kCIInputImageKey: beginImage, kCIInputRadiusKey: radius]
```

Comment: Thanks. NSDictionary doesn't work because of CIFilter signature, it wants `[String:AnyObject]`. Your other idea triggers the same error message but interestingly Xcode now detects another [problem](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/4830da60-b56a-46e2-916f-d80b734fe54b/f567f8540e14ed45/res/c110f3ed-5be4-4ee8-b495-f6a15a8dd53e/skitch.png) one line later (it was hidden earlier I guess, and is not relevant for this question because will be addressed anyway).

Comment: I've updated my question with better description and screenshots.